Styling of comment timestamps becomes similar to usernames when comments are expanded
When clicking the "Show N more comments" on a post the styling of the comment timestamps of other posts on the same page becomes similar to the styling of the comment author's display name.
Reproduction steps:

Open a question that has enough comments for the "Show N more comments" link to show up and also has answers with comments on them. For example open this question: What is the XY problem?
Click the "Show N more comments" on the question.
Scroll to an answer (only comments on other posts on the same page are affected) with comments on the same page.
Notice that the styling of the comment timestamps is wrong.

Styling before clicking "Show N more comments":

Styling after clicking "Show N more comments":


Nice reproduction steps. I noticed this sometimes but didn't know what caused it.

(if you saw my answer before it was deleted) Sorry I mixed up this post with the similar but not quite the same issue here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402284/styling-of-comment-timestamps-becomes-similar-to-usernames-when-i-click-onto-the
This issue still needs to be looked into.

Let's add more comments so people can verify the behavior on this question itself

@JanDoggen comments alone won't work, this bug can only be reproduced on a page that has multiple posts since the issue doesn't happen on the post on which you expand comments but rather on the other posts in the same page.
