Styling of comment timestamps becomes similar to usernames when I click onto the timestamps
Maybe related to this, but the reproduction step aren’t the same and I think it is more related to this new announcement. I think this bug is related to “visited timestamps”.
First way to reproduce:

You can open any questions with comments, like this:





Click onto the timestamps of the comment. After that, the styling of comment timestamps becomes similar to usernames:





Second way to reproduce:

You can go to any users “All action” page and find ”Comments”.
Click on any comment.





After that, the styling of comment timestamps becomes similar to usernames:





Also reported as part of issues with link colours on MSO: Dark Gray/Black is poor choice for colour on visited links. Most likely related to Make visited post titles a more distinct color on Meta.SE as it started happening the same day an answer was posted there. Staff claim this is 10 months old change

When we updated the visited state for links, the comment timestamp links also inherited that new visited state. Comment timestamp links did not have a visited state previously. We have removed the visited state for this link type altogether to resolve this issue.
The fix is now live in production.
This fix also includes an additional change to the text color of the timestamp. The color will be slightly darker (bumping it up by one stop) in order to meet the minimum Lightness contrast (Lc) value of 60.
The change is only being applied to elements that use the comment-date class.
This will also resolve: Please make the timestamps of comments to have only a single color per site
