Please make the timestamps of comments to have only a single color per site
I was surfing in some of SE sites and I found this strange thing: There are two types of colors for the timestamp of a comment (in some sites I think).
Two examples are French site and ELU site:

French site:



In the ELU site the comments under the question itself have red timestamps; and the comments under the answers have gray timestamps:



Of course, there are more sites with this problem.
The gray timestamps aren't good. I think it's better that all timestamps have the theme color of the sites.

Pretty sure one style is "visited" and the other isn't. You visit comment links when you click on the inbox notification or the timestamp directly. However, I agree, this isn't really good for comments since (unlike questions) you usually read them without visiting the link.

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/402284/1376393

Might be a bug, pretty sure it was OK in the past, and changed during one of the many color changes done recently.

@Laurel I'm pretty sure I haven't visited the comment links in the provided ELU example picture.

@Carrott How about this question?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/402284/1376393 Will you add the [tag:status-review] tag?

@user1176409 Who is Carrott?

@Snack Exchange Carrott is a staff on these sites.

@Laurel In some sites the visited comment timestamps have a darker color compared to the unvisited ones. In some other sites it is the opposite.

@user1176409 Yup, slowly working my way through all the related comment link issues.

When we updated the visited state for links, the comment timestamp links also inherited that new visited state. Comment timestamp links did not have a visited state previously. We have removed the visited state for this link type altogether to resolve this issue.
The fix is now live in production.
This fix also includes an additional change to the text color of the timestamp. The color will be slightly darker (bumping it up by one stop) in order to meet the minimum Lightness contrast (Lc) value of 60.
The change is only being applied to elements that use the comment-date class.
This will also resolve: Styling of comment timestamps becomes similar to usernames when I click onto the timestamps

Does this apply to other timestamps? For example, the last activity timestamps on the question lists now have a slight color difference when visited.

@Laurel Confirmed this fix will not be applied to the last activity timestamps on question lists. That uses a different class and the change would need to be made to the post-summary component (from our Stacks library). That fix is likely to take more time (different team, more testing involved). I suggest creating a new post with a request to remove the visited state on that element specifically (if that's what you're hoping for) so we can track it separately.
